# trying to populate dropdown, error in if else condition ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, drop-down-menu, html-select

This is the below code that I had written for populating a dropdown.

```
<html>
<select id = 'status_update' >
    <%  array = [{"status_name"=>"Submitted", "reachable"=>false, "transition_name"=>""}, 
                 {"status_name"=>"Replied", "reachable"=>true, "transition_name"=>"Reply"},
                 {"status_name"=>"Answered", "reachable"=>false, "transition_name"=>""},
                 {"status_name"=>"Closed", "reachable"=>false, "transition_name"=>""},
                 {"status_name"=>"Canceled", "reachable"=>true, "transition_name"=>"Cancel"}]
        array.each { |x|
        x.each do |key, value|
    %>
          <option value = "<%= #{x['transition_name']} %>" 
                  disabled = "<%= if ((#{x['reachable']}) == 'false') 
                                  return 'disabled'
                                  else 
                                  return ''
                                  end %>" ><%=  "#{x['status_name']}" %></option>
    <% end %>
    <% } %>
  </select>
</html>
```

In the above code, `array` is collection of hashmaps and the keys in hashmaps remains the same, 3 keys with different values in each set. Now, I am trying to populate each hashmap, with the values of their respective keys, in the dropdown. When I try so, I am getting error

> ERB syntax error:dropdown:23: syntax error, unexpected kELSE
>
> ```
>                               else
> ```

Might be simple, but not able to get the correct way of approach to get the hashmaps in the dropdown. Can anyone of you kindly let me know how to proceed please ?

Comment: if `reachable` is false in the above code, then `disabled` property of option list value should be `disabled`. The `status_name` should be visible but the user should not be able to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop in not necessary. This should work:

```
<% array.each do |x| %>
  <option value="<%= x['transition_name'] %>" disabled="<%= x['reachable'] ? '' : 'disabled' %>"><%= x['status_name'] %></option>
<% end %>
```

Rather than setting `disabled=""` it's better to omit the attribute:

```
  <option value="<%= x['transition_name'] %>" <%= 'disabled="disabled"' unless x['reachable'] %>"><%= x['status_name'] %></option>
```

Or, if this is too much in one line:

```
<% if x['reachable'] %>
  <option value="<%= x['transition_name'] %>"><%= x['status_name'] %></option>
<% else %>
  <option value="<%= x['transition_name'] %>" disabled="disabled"><%= x['status_name'] %></option>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanx alot. It works. But when `reachable` is `true`, the dropdown value gets disabled for that case too. In my case only when `reachable` is `false` the option should be disabled. How can I do that ?